# How to filter DIVs called by AJAX with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I use a simple jQuery code to filter DIVs with given class. It is based on the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017836/javascript-show-hide-as-filters-to-list-of-divs), and working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJRek/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var links = $('.bound');
    var divs = $('div');
    links.click(function(event){
       divs.hide();
       divs.filter('.' + event.target.id).show();
    });
});
```

This works when the DIVs are originally in the html code; but I call DIVs from an external file via simple jQuery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'external.html', 
  success: function(html){
  $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

How to mix these two simple jQuery codes to work together to filter DIVs provided by ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/nYrUN/

Also have a look at the [jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation. This will give you the abilty to bind events to selectors that aren't even present within the DOM (like objects you attach after an ajax call)

```
$('.bound').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div').hide().filter('.' + event.target.id).show();
});
```

Comment: As the links are always there, there is no need to use `live()` at all. It just adds unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply fetch the `div`s every time a click happens. This way your filters will always work on the current `div`s, no matter when and how you changed them.

```
var links = $('.bound');
links.click(function(event){
   var divs = $('div');
   divs.hide();
   divs.filter('.' + event.target.id).show();
});
```

Comment: @Manuel The OP has never talked about newly added links. There are only newly added divs.